# How do I get a property value from an ApplicationContext object? (not using an annotation)

Tags: spring, spring-el

If I have:

```
@Autowired private ApplicationContext ctx;
```

I can get beans and resources by using one of the the getBean methods. However, I can't figure out how to get property values.

Obviously, I can create a new bean which has an @Value property like:

```
private @Value("${someProp}") String somePropValue;
```

What method do I call on the ApplicationContext object to get that value without autowiring a bean?

I usually use the @Value, but there is a situation where the SPeL expression needs to be dynamic, so I can't just use an annotation.

Comment: (YourBeanType)ctx.getBean("beanId");

Answer (score 72):

In the case where SPeL expression needs to be dynamic, get the property value manually:

```
somePropValue = ctx.getEnvironment().getProperty("someProp");
```

Comment: Using Environment in runtime (as apposed to startup only) is usualy a very bad idea as it goes through JNDI and other locations looking for the value, which is expensive.

Answer (score 21):

If you are stuck on Spring pre 3.1, you can use

```
somePropValue = ctx.getBeanFactory().resolveEmbeddedValue("${someProp}");
```

Comment: This is the answer that works for me with Spring 4.3.3.  Only a context is needed, not a bean value placeholder.

Answer (score 18):

Assuming that the `${someProp}` property comes from a PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer, that makes things difficult. The PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer is a BeanFactoryPostProcessor and as such only available at container startup time. So the properties are not available to a bean at runtime.

A solution would be to create some sort of a value holder bean that you initialize with the property / properties you need.

```
@Component
public class PropertyHolder{

    @Value("${props.foo}") private String foo;
    @Value("${props.bar}") private String bar;

    // + getter methods
}
```

Now inject this PropertyHolder wherever you need the properties and access the properties through the getter methods

Comment: An example would be very useful here.

Comment: @Webnet ok, added a small example

Comment: Doesn't this require that `PropertyHolder` is a managed bean?  I think @HappyEngineer was looking for a solution that isn't a managed bean (as am I).

Comment: @Webnet I understand, but AFAIK that's not possible in Spring (at least not with the PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer mechanism)

Comment: The resolveEmbeddedValue() answer works for me with Spring 4.3.3.  Only a context is needed, not a bean value placeholder.

Comment: @Wheezil sure. the downside is that this makes the application aware of the container, which is considered an architectural smell. But if it works for you, go for it

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd agreed... my specific case is for unit testing where I can get away with being a little sloppy.