# Looping through all the properties in a file, with spring and java

Tags: java, spring, properties

Normally i would populate a field using annotations when I knew the property name like so :

```
@Value("${myproperties.myValue}")
private String myString
```

However I now want to loop through all the properties in a file, when their names are unknown, and store both there value and name. What's  the best way with spring and java ?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Actually if you need only to read properties from a file and not to use these properties in Spring's property placeholders, then the solution is simple

```
public class Test1 {
    @Autowired
    Properties props;

    public void printProps() {
        for(Entry<Object, Object> e : props.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
```

...

```
<util:properties id="props" location="/spring.properties" />
```

Comment: Thanks! Note that you need to import  `java.util.Map.Entry` for this to work - I'm new to Java and didn't realise this

Comment: Is that java.util.Properties or some other from spring fwk?

Answer (score 1):

The `@Value` mechanism works through the `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` which is in turn a `BeanFactoryPostProcessor`. The properties used by it are not exposed at runtime. See [this previous answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10823326/342852) for a possible solution.

Answer (score 1):

I could not find a simpler solution than this

```
class PropertyPlaceholder extends PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer {
    Properties props;

    @Override
    protected Properties mergeProperties() throws IOException {
        props = super.mergeProperties();
        return props;
    }
}

public class Test1 {
    @Autowired
    PropertyPlaceholder pph;

    public void printProps() {
        for(Entry<Object, Object> e : pph.props.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    ...
```

...

```
<bean class="test.PropertyPlaceholder">
    <property name="locations">
        <value>/app.properties</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: thx, but how I would access the actual property values, and names ?

Comment: added Test1.printProps as an example

Answer (score -1):

[Using enumeration to loop through Properties](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0140__Collections/UsingEnumerationtoloopthroughProperties.htm)