# How to read from application.properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to read from application.properties and I can't get it working.

this is my code:

```
package config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;

@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class PropertiesReader {

        @Autowired
        private Environment env;

        public String readProperty(String key) {
            return env.getProperty(key);
        }


}
```

this is where I invoke the readProperty:

```
public class JwtSettings {

    public String key;

    public long expiration;

    //The JWT signature algorithm we will be using to sign the token
    public SignatureAlgorithm signatureAlgorithm = SignatureAlgorithm.HS256;

    public JwtSettings() {
        PropertiesReader propertiesReader = new PropertiesReader();
        key = propertiesReader.readProperty(ApplicationProperties.JWT_KEY.key);
    }
```

When I run this code, the env instance is null.
My application.properties file is located in the resource folder.
I'm out of ideas, please help.

Comment: You are overthinking things. Spring Boot already reads the `application.properties` you don't need to do it again.

Comment: so your'e saying I need to remove '@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")' annotation ?

Comment: Yes and if you need properties just inject them with `@Value` or bind to a custom properties object (all of this is explained in the Spring Boot reference guide).

Comment: I'm still getting null for the env instance

Comment: Then you are creating an instance yourself instead of letting Spring create one and inject it.

Comment: can you please give me an example??

Comment: As I saw in your comment, your JwtSettings class is used with @Service annotation and I guess it is instantiated by Spring.

I cannot see any usage of any instance of your ApplicationService in your JwtSettings. Where do you use your ApplicationService?

Comment: its a mistake, I was trying change some things

Answer (score 1):

Try to use your configuration like this:

```
@Service 
public class JwtSettings {

   private String key;

   private long expiration;

   //The JWT signature algorithm we will be using to sign the token
   public SignatureAlgorithm signatureAlgorithm = SignatureAlgorithm.HS256;

   @Autowired
   public JwtSettings(PropertiesReader propertiesReader) {
      this.key = propertiesReader.readProperty(ApplicationProperties.JWT_KEY.key);
   }
}
```

You should never instantiate Spring managed components yourself (by invoking the constructor in your code). Instead you should use Spring Dependency-Injection via `@Autowired` to make sure that all your dependencies are resolved correctly.

To inject properties with Spring (generally):

If you try to get access to a property value from a property resource, try to inject it with Springs `@Value` annotation.

Your application.properties may look like:

```
myproperty.test1=mytestvalue
myproperty.test2=123
```

Now you have a Spring component, where you want to use the property values and you inject them like:

```
@Component
private class MyTestComponent {

   @Value("${myproperty.test1:mydefaultvalue}")
   private String test1Value;

   @Value("${myproperty.test2:-1}")
   private int test2Value;

}
```

Of course you can use other datatypes than String for your property.

Comment: I want to read the application.properties dynamically by using different 'keys'

Comment: So you have runtime computed keys you want to get resolved? Otherwise you can ofc inject ad many different properties by their keys as you want to.

Comment: can you please give me an example?

Comment: I will adapt the above one, to show different keys by injection. For runtime computed keys you may want to have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10822951/how-do-i-get-a-property-value-from-an-applicationcontext-object-not-using-an-a).

Comment: You say that your env instance is null. Maybe you try to access the instance (i.e. call readProperty) before Autowiring takes place as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19421092/autowired-environment-is-null)?

Comment: No that's not the case, because the readProperty is invoked in a endpoint

Comment: I guess your configuration is correctly created by Spring and injected into your Controller/Service? Could you please try to inject the Environment directly into your Controller/Service?

Comment: I don't really understand what do you mean by injecting the Environment to My Controller/Service can you please add some more details ?

Comment: Can you please show me how exactly you call your readProperty function?

Comment: @Service
public class JwtSettings {
 
 public String key;
 
 public long expiration;
 
 //The JWT signature algorithm we will be using to sign the token
 public SignatureAlgorithm signatureAlgorithm = SignatureAlgorithm.HS256;

 
 public JwtSettings() {
  PropertiesReader propertiesReader = new PropertiesReader();
  key = propertiesReader.readProperty(ApplicationProperties.JWT_KEY.key);
 }
}

Comment: Can you please add this with code formatting to your question, so I can open another answer?

Comment: have a look now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160494/discussion-between-l-hanke-and-gal-sosin).